# ReverseInteger code in javafx

Tags: user-interface, recursion, javafx

Am a super-beginner but think it is fun learning. However I have this code for reversing an Integer in a recursive manner,which pretty much works.

I would like to make this into a javafx type program with two textfields. One textfield for input and one to display the reversed integer. As well as implement a button("Reverse") and actionevent to display in the second textfield. I pretty much have the layout for the fields and button but struggling with implementing the reverseInteger code, and parseInt.

Here is the code I have which prints to console:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// Create scanner for input


    System.out.print("Enter integer to be reversed,please,Sir: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The reversed number is ");
                                          // Instanceof
    ReverseIntFirst inst = new ReverseIntFirst();
    inst.reverseInteger(number);
  }

  public void reverseInteger(int value) {
    if (value != 0) { // Basis
      System.out.print(value % 10);
      value = value / 10;
      reverseInteger(value); //Recursive
    }
  }
}
```

// Thank you

So, I have made some code with some of what I need, and slightly edited my first one, but are somewhat clueless on how to get any further. That means how to modify and make the reverseInteger (int Value) work in GUI environment. Should have signature, public int reverseInteger(int value).

My book does not seem to cover the "conversion" into UI too good.

Under is my new code:

```
double paneWidth = 500;
double paneHeight = 250;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


      // Textfield for entering user input, example 43223
      TextField tfOrgNumber = new TextField();
      tfOrgNumber.setPromptText("Enter number");
      tfOrgNumber.getText();

      // Textfield to display the reversed integer from user input
      TextField tfRevNumber = new TextField();
      tfRevNumber.setPromptText("Reversed number");

      // Alignment for textfields 
      tfOrgNumber.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
      tfRevNumber.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

      // Create button
      Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");


      // New pane, adding tf`s and bt
      GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.add(new Label("Your number"), 0, 0);
        pane.add(tfOrgNumber, 1, 0);
        pane.add(new Label("Your reversed number"), 0, 1);
        pane.add(tfRevNumber, 1, 1);//*
        pane.add(btReverse,1,2);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, paneWidth, paneHeight);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Reverse Integer"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage


       // Eventhandler for button
        btReverse.setOnAction( e-> }

 /*public void reverseInteger(int value) {     // <---- What I am having trouble with is implementing this part as public int
                                               // I know i can use parseInt to fetch int from textfield , but not really how to do it.
        if (value != 0) { // Basis
          System.out.print(value % 10);
          value = value / 10;
          reverseInteger(value); //Recursive
        }*/

 // Integer.parseInt(tfOrgNumber.getText());




public static void main(String[] args) { // Main method 
    System.out.println("");
    launch(args);
```

}}

Thanks for any response, guys. Appreciate it!

Comment: Which is the problem you are facing? Why are you printing the module between number and 10?

Comment: Come up with a version of the `reverseInteger` method that returns `int` or `String` and then access the `text` properties in the event handler of the button... Not sure which part you're having difficulties with..

Comment: Make an attempt, then come back with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a specific question.

Comment: Ive made some changes and added code for buttons and textfields.  Any help is appreciated.thanks